# How do I iterate and compute values from an array in the MongoDB Aggregation Framework?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am writing an aggregation pipeline with MongoDB. The pipeline has several phases such as Match, then Project, Group, Match, and Sort.

At this point of the pipeline, I have data of the form:

```js
name : "Bob"
values : [{date: ISODate("2014-01-01T00:00:00Z"), count: 12},
          {date: ISODate("2014-01-04T00:00:00Z"), count: 50},
          {date: ISODate("2014-02-15T00:00:00Z"), count: 8},
         ]
```

Please note the *date* fields are sorted.

The question is how, within the MongoDB Aggregation Framework, to compute **the count value relative to the previous one within the sorted array** (the group key being "name").

I would like to transform the above document to have computed relative values:

```js
name : "Bob"
values : [{date: ISODate("2014-01-01T00:00:00Z"), count: 12}, // 12 = 12 - 0
          {date: ISODate("2014-01-04T00:00:00Z"), count: 38}, // 38 = 50 - 12 
          {date: ISODate("2014-02-15T00:00:00Z"), count: -30},// -30 = 8 - 38
         ]
```

The purpose being to then unwind the array, and to group by date.

I know it is possible to do it with map-reduce, but I would prefer to do it within the aggregation framework.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No it is not possible with the aggregation framework. You have already stated you know it is possible with mapReduce, and that is because you can use a "scope" variable as a "global" to be referenced in various stages. That is not available to the aggregation framework. Feel free to submit a JIRA asking for "globals"

Comment: A relevant Jira issue to watch/upvote is [SERVER-4437: support windowing operation on pipelines](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-4437).